I don't understand the proof that extensions that aren't separable have 0 trace in Keith Conrad's norm and trace notes.

I don't understand the proof that extensions that aren't separable have $0$ trace in Keith Conrad's norm and trace notes.

I don't understand the following argument. This argument is used while proving that trace is zero for non-separable extensions (Lemma 2.2).
Let $L/k$ be an extension and $a \in L$. Let char$(k) = p > 0$.
Assume $L/k(a)$ isn't separable.
Then, $[L:k(a)]$ is divisible by the inseparability degree $[L:k(a)]_{i}>1$ in $\Bbb Z$ and so is divisible by $p$, whence $[L:k(a)] = 0$ in $k$.
I don't understand the bold part. Why would this imply that the degree of the extension is $0$ in $k$? What does that even mean? Isn't the degree of the extension always an integer?

"The integer $[L:k(a)]$ is $0$ in $k$" is just a shorthand for "the canonical image in $k$ of this integer is $0$".
It implies that $\operatorname{Tr}_{L/k}(a)$ is $0$ because (as stated at the top of the same page in the notes) this element of $k$ is always equal to
$[L:k(a)]\operatorname{Tr}_{k(a)/k}(a)$.
